# Trying to iterate my function many times using i

Tags: r, loops, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to iterate a for loop many times but it's only printing out once.

```
sample_gamma <- function(alpha, beta, n, iter) {
  mean_s = c()
  mean_sd = c()
  for(i in 1:iter){
    a = rgamma(n, shape = alpha, scale = 1/beta) 
    return(c(mean(a), sd(a)))
    }
```

Comment: Put the return statement out of the loop, don't overwrite a each iteration.

Comment: It's still printing only once.

Comment: Do you only want to print the output or do you want to save it in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for this

```
sample_gamma <- function(alpha, beta, n, iter) {
  mean_s = c()
  mean_sd = c()
  for(i in 1:iter){
    a = rgamma(n, shape = alpha, scale = 1/beta) 
    print(c(mean(a), sd(a)))
  }
}
```

Comment: There you go. Thank you! I thought 'print' was a python function.  Thank you!